# Override fail with error

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Using Sencha Touch 2.0.0 I am trying to override a class's behaviour.
I am following these [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext-method-define) and this [forum post on the subject](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?173350-Concerns-over-Ext.override%28%29-being-deprecated)
But with the following code:

```
Ext.define('MP.service.Override', {
    extend: 'Ext.Base',
    override: 'Ext.Ajax',

    request: function(cfg) {
        console.log('overriden');
        this.callOverridden(arguments);
    }
});
```

I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'override'
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ext.Ajax class is a singleton instance of the Ext.data.Connection class so it cannot be overridden this way.

You can replace the function of the singleton rather than creating a 'proper' override.

One way would be to do the following:

```
Ext.Ajax.request = Ext.Function.createInterceptor(Ext.Ajax.request, function(){ 
    console.log('override');
});
```

The only issue with this is that you can only add your new code *before* the original function but similar techniques can get you round this issue.

A related question can be found here: [sencha touch override ext.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971028/sencha-touch-override-ext-ajax)