# sencha touch override ext.ajax

Tags: ajax, extjs, sencha-touch, overriding, sencha-architect

I'm writing a sencha touch app using sencha architect. Because my app do lot of ajax request, most of it need to send 'token' in request header for authentication. So I think of create child class base on Ext.Ajax which always has 'token' in request header. Then I can use this child class without care of the header.

```
MyApp.override.Ajax.request({ ... })
```

I try define this in app/override/Ajax.js

```
Ext.define('Myapp.override.Ajax', {
  override: 'Ext.Ajax',
  headers: {
      'token': 'test'
  }
});
```

I also set this as 'requires' in Application. But get error when try to call

```
Myapp.override.Ajax.request({ ... })
```

Seem Myapp can not locate .override package (MyApp.override  is undifined)

How to let MyApp know override package or what is the correct/best way to do this.

A quick example is very appreciated. Thank you very much.

Update info:

override file location: app\override\Ajax.js

html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script>
    var Ext = Ext || {};
    Ext.theme = {
        name: "Default"
    };
</script>
<script src="sencha-touch-all-debug.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/sencha-touch.css">
<script src="app/override/Ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

app.js file

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({

});

Ext.application({

requires: [
    'MyApp.override.Ajax'
],
views: [
    'ContactDetailView'
],
name: 'MyApp'
...
```

App can start without error, but when call MyApp.override.Ajax.request : Cannot read property 'Ajax' of undefined , mean  MyApp.override is undefined

**Update**

Here something news, it better but not working yet.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Ajax', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Connection',
singleton: true,

request: function( options ) {
    this.constructor(options, options.url);
console.log(options);
    options.header = {'Token':'mytoken'};
    this.callParent( options );
}
});
```

and error when try MyApp.Ajax.request() . I'm sure that options.url is exist in options by check the log

```
[ERROR][Ext.data.Connection#request] No URL specified
```

I add extend from constructor function

```
constructor : function (config, url)
{
    config = config || {};
//config.url = 'google.com';
    this.initConfig(config);
    this.callParent(config);
},
```

Error just disappear when I remove comment from config.url = 'google.com'; but it comes that the config.url there is ajax request url but local file url ??? I see from chrome console and network ?

```
GET file:///C:/MyApp/assets/www/google.com?_dc=1370855149720
```

Please help. thanks.

Comment: What does your require statement looks like? And how did you configure Ext.Loader? If the require works, the Loader should try to load a file, and you should set a failed GET request in the console, giving you the URL tried by the Loader. That may help you to debug.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just add more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, this is work with me

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Ajax', {    
    extend: 'Ext.data.Connection',

    singleton: true,

    request: function( options ) {
        options.headers = {
            Token: 'mytoken',
        };
        this.callParent( [options] );
    }
});
```

And this simple do what i want too, great.

```
Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', (function(conn, options, eOpts) {  
    options.headers = {
        Token: 'mytoken',
    };
}), this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to agree with yourself about the name of your override class:

- Myapp.override.Ajax
- Lunex.override.Ajax
- Myapp.override.data.proxy.Ajax

Which one is it? Pay attention to this, the Loader won't go easy about it...

Anyway, you seem a bit confused about `override` and `extend`.

`extend` does create a new class from the parent class, with the modifications you've specified. Then you can use the class you defined, like you're trying to do.

`override`, on the other hand, applies the modification to the existing class. In this case, the class name is only used for the require statement, and by the loader. No actual class is created. So, in your example, the namespace `MyApp.override` is not defined, hence the error. Nevertheless, whenever you use `Ext.Ajax`, your custom header should be sent. Provided you're manager to load your file, that is ;p

Now, your case is a bit special because `Ext.Ajax` is a **singleton** instance of [`Ext.data.Connection`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection). See its [code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/Ajax2.html#Ext-Ajax), there's not much in there. And while overriding a singleton can make sense, extending from it would be disturbing.

So, what you were probably trying to do is that:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.Ajax', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Connection',
    headers: {
        'token': 'test'
    }
});
```

So that you can do:

```
Myapp.Ajax.request({ ... });
```

Whether the best choice here is to override or to extend is a tough question. I'm glad you didn't ask it!

Comment: Sorry about the class name. I change my code to something general for easy to read but make mistake. I udpated the code. And thankd for the override and extend. I will try your suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the config 'defaultHeaders' in your extended class? In that way it's always added to your headers.

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-cfg-defaultHeaders

From the source of Ext.data.Connection

```
setupHeaders: function(xhr, options, data, params) {
    var me = this,
        headers = Ext.apply({}, options.headers || {}, me.getDefaultHeaders() || {}),
        contentType = me.getDefaultPostHeader(),
        jsonData = options.jsonData,
        xmlData = options.xmlData,
        key,
        header;
```